# heos app detect other wireless speaker

Tags: wifi, dlna

I have 3 heos speakers in my house and a 4th wireless (wifi) speaker that I built myself.  I was wondering if anyone else has tried tinkering around with the heos app to make it detect other wifi speakers and play music to them?

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using dlna to get my logitech/squeeze boxes and heos speakers to play the same music, which worked but there was a significant delay between the two systems that I couldn't correct with the squeezebox software settings.

Right now the only way to hook up to existing speakers is with a HEOS Link, but that is a pretty large and costly device.  It would be great if Denon created a playback-only HEOS dongle that with a line out--call it a Linklite.  It wouldn't necessarily need to be able to do everything a normal HEOS device does, at a minimum it would just play what is played to your other HEOS device(s). But nearly all wifi speakers have a line-in jack, even Sonos.  It would be kind of cool to be able to easily add third party components in this way.

Wishful thinking: if HEOS becomes a more popular home entertainment operating system, perhaps vendors of the other products will embed the software required to be compatible with HEOS.